# Multiple file Upload

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

How to upload multiple file in any location. My Problem is that i am selecting multiple files but when i click on the upload button only last one file is uploaded with rename name and the rename name is all file name append with comma like this `(file1,file2,flie3)`

Here is the code

```
File saveFile = null;
String tempPath = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
saveFile = new File(tempPath + File.separator + fileUploadFileName);
FileUtils.copyFile(fileUpload, saveFile);
```

Comment: Have a look into : http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/servlet/java-multiple-files-upload-example

Comment: @Anup also consider upvoting the answer to the question that your is duplicate of, if you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

By using Apache commons fileupload FileItem, the sample code will be like this

```
try {
            // parses the request's content to extract file data
            List formItems = upload.parseRequest(request);
            Iterator iter = formItems.iterator();

            // iterates over form's fields
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                FileItem item = (FileItem) iter.next();
                // processes only fields that are not form fields
                if (!item.isFormField()) {
                    String fileName = new File(item.getName()).getName();
                    String filePath = uploadPath + File.separator + fileName;
                    File storeFile = new File(filePath);

                    // saves the file on disk
                    item.write(storeFile);
                }
            }
            request.setAttribute("message", "Upload has been done successfully!");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            request.setAttribute("message", "There was an error: " + ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Download MultipleFilesUpload.zip from [Multi File Upload](http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/servlet/java-multiple-files-upload-example). Refer to this [Upload](http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/servlet/apache-commons-fileupload-example-with-servlet-and-jsp) for more details :