# Uploading multiple files using jsp?

Tags: java, jsp

How can I fix this code below to upload multiple files. It works good when I upload single file.

Using libraries

1. commons-fileupload-1.2.2
2. org.apache.commons.io.jar

index.jsp

```
<%@page import="java.io.*" %>  

    <%@page import="jxl.*"%>
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>File upload</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Uploading files</h1>
        <form name="uploadForm" action= "index.jsp" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file" value="" multiple="multiple" width="100"/>
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="submit" multiple="multiple"/> 
            <%

                String saveFile= new String();
                //get content type
                String contentType=request.getContentType();
                // make sure first of all not null
                if((contentType!=null)&&(contentType.indexOf("multipart/form-data")>=0))
                {
                    // begin to read a files
                    // creating DataInputStream
                    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(request.getInputStream());
                    //get content links of the request
                    int formDataLength= request.getContentLength();
                    // equal size
                    byte dataBytes[]= new byte[formDataLength];
                    int totalBytesRead=0;
                    int byteRead;
                    while(totalBytesRead<formDataLength)
                    {
                        byteRead=in.read(dataBytes,totalBytesRead,formDataLength);
                        totalBytesRead+=byteRead;

                    }
                    //convert it to string  
                    String file= new  String(dataBytes);
                    saveFile= file.substring(file.indexOf("filename=\"")+10);
                    saveFile= saveFile.substring(0,saveFile.indexOf("\n"));
                    saveFile= saveFile.substring(saveFile.lastIndexOf("\\")+1, saveFile.indexOf("\""));

                    int lastIndex= contentType.lastIndexOf("=");

                    String boundary=contentType.substring(lastIndex+1, contentType.length());

                    int pos;
                    pos=file.indexOf("filename=\"");
                    pos=file.indexOf("\n",pos)+1;
                    pos=file.indexOf("\n",pos)+1;
                    pos=file.indexOf("\n",pos)+1;

                    int boundaryLocation=file.indexOf(boundary,pos)-4;
                    // get length of position
                    int startPos=((file.substring(0,pos)).getBytes()).length;
                    int endPos=((file.substring(0,boundaryLocation)).getBytes()).length;

                    saveFile="C:/upload/"+saveFile;
                    //creating a file object
                    File ff = new File(saveFile);
                    try{
                        //creating a FileOutputStream object
                        FileOutputStream fileOut= new FileOutputStream(ff);
                        fileOut.write(dataBytes, startPos, endPos-startPos);
                        fileOut.flush();
                        fileOut.close();
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){
                        out.print(e);
                    }       

                }


            %>


        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Have a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32471642/multiple-file-upload/32472421#32472421

Comment: it's not what i mean. I want to choose multiple files at the same time.s

Comment: The link in side that post does the same. http://www.codejava.net/java-ee/servlet/java-multiple-files-upload-example

Comment: But one time, you only can add one file . If you want to upload 1000 files, you will have to spend a lot of time. I mean, i can add multiple files at the same time and upload all of them to server.

Comment: Why you aren't using Apache file up-loader in your code? As you have already added those libraries to the classpath.

Comment: http://texantek.com/forums/java/6143-uploading-multiple-files-in-jsp is one more useful link

Comment: thankyou , i'll try to do this.